# JPA Hibernate - Unknown Entity on excluded class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit

When I run my test class called UserServiceTest I get this error. The weird thing is, I am not trying to persist an instance of the UserServiceTest type.

The code which it fails on. If I comment out this code the rest of the tests run and I dont get this error.

```
User persistedUser = new User() {
    {
        setUsername("Jan123");
        setName("Jan");
        setText("test bio");
        setLocation("<location>");
        setWebsite("<website>");
    }
};

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(persistedUser);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
>   UserServiceTest$1     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at
>   UserServiceTest.setUp(UserServiceTest.java:55)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Here is my persistence.xml. I checked that it is used by malforming the XML on purpose to see if it throws an XML parsing error, which it does. Tables are created just fine, as I can see in the output of the build and in the SQL Server Management Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="KwetterPUTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Kweet</class>
    <class>User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=KwetterTest;" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Edit: Here is the relevant code from the UserServiceTest. I did a usage search in NetBeans for any instances of UserServiceTest that I perhaps wrongfully instantiated. There are none.

```
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private static EntityManager entityManager;
    private static UserService userService;
    private static User persistedUser;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("KwetterPUTest");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        userService = new UserService(new UserDAOJPAImpl(entityManager));
        persistedUser = new User() {
            {
                setUsername("Jan123");
                setName("Jan");
                setText("test bio");
                setLocation("<location>");
                setWebsite("<website>");
            }
        };

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(persistedUser);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Edit 2: pom file for those who are interested. I used the latest 4.x version of Hibernate as well as the latest 5.x and 5.2.2. None changed anything.

> ```
> <dependencies>        
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.12</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>         <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
>         <version>7.2.1.jre8</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>         <version>8.0</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

Comment: Can you please show the code of UserServiceTest

Comment: Just edited the post and included the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are instantiating the User class like this:

```
persistedUser = new User() {
        {
            setUsername("Jan123");
            setName("Jan");
            setText("test bio");
            setLocation("<location>");
            setWebsite("<website>");
        }
    };
```

This will creates an inner class of type: `UserServiceTest$1`

And this class is not recognized by Hibernate as the stack trace says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
>   UserServiceTest$1

You must do it like this:

```
persistedUser = new User();
persistedUser.setUsername("Jan123");
persistedUser.setName("Jan");
persistedUser.setText("test bio");
persistedUser.setLocation("<location>");
persistedUser.setWebsite("<website>");
```

Comment: Please remove the location and website from your comment. I just edited the original post as well. its private info. Other than that, thanks very much for the solution! It works great. I was pulling my hair out. I had no idea that it would create an inner class of that type.

Comment: I removed it but in the question is still the location